# Quick and acceptable MP3 streaming solution

Tags: jquery, flash, audio, streaming, mp3

I have to do a job overnight to enable a very simple interface for users listening to a radio channel over the internet. I am wondering what is the best soluition for streaming. I thought of QuickTime, but it requires users to have it installed and I am not quite sure Quicktime is as spread as flash. So I tend to implement something in flash. Do you have any suggestions on a good tool (it may be really simple, the simpler, the better)?

I don't want playlists and nothing like that. The website is built with DotNetNuke and it manages all the interactions. I just want to insert in the page that little bar that allows users to play/pause and drag to another part of the show. I will pass a parameter with the file URL and the player should manage the rest.

It won't be a live streaming, but rather streaming of MP3 files hosted in the server.

By the way, I found this project (http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/) which is a jQuery plugin and it seems interesting. Does any one know it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a programming question; it is more of a software query;  although I personally find it interesting, it does not involve any code neither in the question nor the answer.  I vote to close.

Answer (score 11):

Use a flash embedded mp3 player.  it can play mp3 play list or individual files.

Using jw player (http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) will let you create xml playlists easily.  It's ready to go out of the box.

With JW Player you can specify a filename from the URL, meaning you could pass in the link as a url variable and not have to use an XML file. I recall XSPF player can do that too, but I use JW Player more.

Xspf player is another free mp3 player that is flash based..
http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/

If you want something more you can check out a google search like this one.  this should be enough to get you going.

http://www.google.ca/search?q=free+flash+mp3+player&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 6):

SoundManager very similar to JWPlayer but does not require paying for a license:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Nice player, thanks for sharing.  Have you found it to be as flexible as jwplayer?

Comment: For handling audio, yes.  I can't think of anything that JWPlayer does that this doesn't, off the top of my head.  I have not explored the video playing functionality, but the demo seems to suggest that is flexible as well: 

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/video/

Answer (score 2):

The [XSPF player](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/) is exceptional. I used the slim player on a rush job and had it running in about 10 minutes.

The only thing is that you need to make an [XSPF file](http://www.xspf.org/specs/) that contains the MP3's details like track name. But the format is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

niftyPlayer 1.7 is the smallest MP3 player available its based on flash n plays single files for now...
**Upsides**
Small (~4kb)
Free, open-source
No Flash knowledge required: file URL is specified in HTML
JavaScript-ready! You may even bypass the Flash interface altogether!
Autostart capability
Draggable/Clickable seek bar
Simple operation with Play/Pause and Stop buttons
Buffering with progress bar
Buffering is stoppable! (through Stop button)
Volume control
Very verbal
Retries upon encountering errors
**Downsides**
No playlist capability (but can be done in JavaScript!)
No photo-slideshow or video capability
Sound must be MP3 (flash limitation)